# NextJS 13.4.7 (app routes) Dynamic routes 404 status code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, custom-error-pages

I'm currently building a NextJS 13.4.7 application with dynamic routes and a Headless cms coming from Contentful. All routes are open to use, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

We want to get the data from the CMS. If there is no data for this page (slug) we need to throw a `Notfound()`. Until this point everything works fine. However the Notfound() wont trigger a statuscode 404 on the server which will result in loss of SEO. The Notfound() custom page is triggered but no 404 status code is returned.

Is there a possibility to throw the notFound() with a 404 status code?

*edit added code

/app/[...slug]/page.tsx

```
export default async function ContentPageRoute({ params }) {
  const pathname = `/${params.slug.join("/")}`;

  const { pageCollection } = await getPageBySlug({
    slug: pathname,
  });

  const page = pageCollection?.items[0];

  if (!isDefined(page)) notFound();

  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading">
      <ContentPage
        breadcrumbs={
          <Breadcrumbs style="containerWithSpaceBottom" pathname={pathname} />
        }
        page={page}
      />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

/app/notfound.tsx

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <p className="mt-5 mb-3 container-padding text-center">
      De pagina kon helaas niet worden gevonden
    </p>
  );
}
```

With resulting in this request:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your code?

Comment: @AudunHilden Will this do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your `notfound.tsx` file to `not-found.tsx`.

You didn't show how you import `notFound` in your code, but make sure it's matching the one below:

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
```

Comment: I renamed the file notfound.tsx to not-found.tsx and imported the notFound like above. Unfortunately still no status code. The not-found.tsx is correctly loaded but the status code is still a 200 message.

Comment: Can you try renaming it to `not-found.js`?

Comment: I just found the solution, Thanks for helping me. 

I had a suspense in the rootlayout which will result in rendering the page before the notFound could be triggered. So removing the suspense fixed the issue.

Comment: Mind checking if it still works if you name your file `notfound.tsx` as you originally had?

Comment: Correct, notfound.tsx is not working, not-found.tsx is working IF i dont use the suspense function. Thanks!